# Automatically implementing `From` with `thiserror::Error` fails for `std::error::Error` with `#from` directive

Tags: rust

**I'm getting this error:**

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `&ArchiveError`
  --> src/archive.rs:45:38
   |
42 | fn extract<R: Read + Seek>(filename: &'static str) -> Result<(), &ArchiveError> {
   |                                                       ------------------------- expected `&ArchiveError` because of this
...
45 |             ArchiveZip::new(filename)?
   |                                      ^ the trait `From<&dyn std::error::Error>` is not implemented for `&ArchiveError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <ArchiveError as From<&'static (dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>
   = note: required by `from`
```

**I have the following error definition:**

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum ArchiveError {
    #[error("Zip file operation failed: {0}")]
    ArchiveZipError(#[from] &'static dyn std::error::Error),
}
```

**Removing the `'static` lifetime specifier renders this error:**

```
    ArchiveZipError(#[from] &dyn std::error::Error),
    => Missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
```

**With this calling function:**

```rust
fn extract<R: Read + Seek>(filename: &'static str) -> Result<(), &ArchiveError> {
    match get_extension_from_filename(filename) {
        Some("zip") => {
            ArchiveZip::new(filename)?
                .extract("foo")
                .or(Err(&ArchiveError::ArchiveZipError(&ZipError::InvalidArchive(filename))))
        }
        None => Err(&ArchiveError::ArchiveTypeNotDetectedError),
    }
}
```

**With these functions:**

```rust
impl<'a> Extractable<'a> for ArchiveZip<'a> {
    fn new(path: &'a str) -> Result<&ArchiveZip, &dyn Error> {
        let reader = ArchiveZip::get_file_reader(path)?;
        Ok(&ArchiveZip { path, archive: ZipArchive::new(reader)? })
    }

    fn get_file_reader(path: &str) -> Result<&mut dyn ReadSeek, &dyn Error> {
        Ok(&mut File::open(path)?)
    }
}
```

**How is the `#from` directive not working?**

Comment: Your code is... problematic. References, `&T`, only *borrow* the value they're referencing which means something else has to *own* them. Unfortunately, the owners for a lot of your objects are just variables/temporaries in functions that go out of scope, which would render the resulting references immediately invalid.

Comment: Errors normally own their data, so you'll likely have better results if you replace `&'static dyn std::error::Error` with `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`.

Comment: @user4815162342: How do I get a `Box` to work with the `#from` directive of the `thiserror::Error` automatic conversion thing? (Not that I got it working with the reference anyway, which you can see from my question...). I tried using `Box` for both the result type and the error type before, and it wouldn't convert.

Comment: @Neil Can you provide a small and self-sufficient example that shows what doesn't work for you? I find it hard to understand that from your question. And where does the `Extractable` trait come from? If that's something you defined, then maybe that's the source of your issues, because its `new` method specifies the extremely strange return type of `Result<&ArchiveZip, &dyn Error>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` instead of `&dyn Error` works.

I also changed:

```rust
    ArchiveZipError(#[from] &dyn std::error::Error),
```

To this:

```rust
    ArchiveZipError(#[from] ZipError),
```